# How to apply strikethrough formatting on space character in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I would like to apply the strikethrough formatting on the space character in MS Word. My purpose is primarily aesthetic, although that should not make much difference. Currently the strikethrough formatting ignores space characters, and I do not see any option to make it do otherwise.

Please advise.

**Edited (28 October 18):** Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I would like the strikethrough to apply to space at the end of a string or on a string with only space characters.

PS: I have found the solution, stated below.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you currently get. I've just opened Word 2016 and written "Hello World" and then put a strikethrough which did the words and the space between. I then did some further typing (including spaces) and the strikethrough followed every single character...

Comment: +1, I get strike through in white space using 2016.

Comment: Kinnecrus is correct. I can use the strikethrough formatting on space character in Word properly. Maybe you can repair Office (Control Panel > Programs and Features, select Office, click Change > Repair) and install the updates for Word to have a try.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity guys. Edited the question and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply strikethrough to space at the end of a string or on a string with only space characters, the nonbreaking space characters should be used instead of the regular space character.

The non-breaking space can be typed using ctrl+shift+space and appears as ° when toggling the *show paragraph mark* feature of MS Word.

1. Toggle *show paragraph mark* on
2. Type as many nonbreaking space characters as required.
3. Highlight the non-breaking space characters and apply the strikethrough
4. Toggle *show paragraph mark* off

Answer (score 1):

Using Word 2016 whitespace gets a strikethrough, as well as any highlighted or typed text, when strikethrough formatting is enabled. This appears to be default behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this and apologies for my ambiguous opening. I've stated the specifics now and also found the solution and will post it. Feel free to ad the awesome screen cast if you can :)